# How to exclude only one character in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract something out of a string. For example the string is:

```
s = "xxx text, yyy"
expected = "xxx text"

s = "xxx text yyy"
expected = "xxx text"

s = "xxx [text] yyy"
expected = "xxx [text]"

s = "xxx text,"
expected = "xxx text"

s = "xxx text "
expected = "xxx text"
```

My current code is:

```
re.search(r'xxx \S+', s)
```

So, in my regex, I can't exclude the comma `','`. I know `[^,]` can exclude the comma, but how can I combine it with `\S`.

In my case, I have to use `'\S'`, my requirement is just to exclude the comma based on `\S`.

I tried regex assertation: `re.search(r'xxx (\S+(?!\,))', s).groups()`, but it still extracted the comma.

Comment: Why not just use `s.split(',', 1)[0]`? why do you need regex?

Comment: You could use the word boundary ? like `re.search(r'xxx \b\S+\b', s).group()`, or depending on the use case, just a mere `str.split` might suffice

Comment: @Sayse Hi, this is just a simple demo, considering other factors, I need to use regex.

Comment: @DennisLi You need to show the correct input for the correct answer. The more the sample input, the better

Comment: @hansolo thanks for your remind, I'll add more examples.

Comment: You need to create an actual [mcve]. Your question looks like it has nothing to do with extracting a single character but infact trying to extract `xxx text`

Comment: @Sayse, Thanks for your correcting.  I have added some example and code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two ways to do the job:

```
s="xxx text, yyy"
# if there is ALLWAYS a comma after.
res = re.search(r'xxx \S+(?=,)', s)
print(res.group())
# else
res = re.search(r'xxx [^\s,]+', s)
print(res.group())
```

**Update according to new test cases:**

```
ar = [
    "xxx text, yyy",
    "xxx text yyy",
    "xxx [text] yyy",
    "xxx text,",
    "xxx text ",
    "xxx text",
]
for s in ar:
    # choose one of them
    print(re.search(r'xxx \S+?(?=,|\s|$)', s).group())
    print(re.search(r'xxx [^\s,]+', s).group())
    print
```

**Output:**

```
xxx text
xxx text

xxx text
xxx text

xxx [text]
xxx [text]

xxx text
xxx text

xxx text
xxx text

xxx text
xxx text
```

Comment: Thanks Toto, there is not always comma after, I have updated the input and expected output in question.

Comment: @DennisLi: The second regex works for all your test cases. For the first one, just change it to `r'xxx \S+?(?=,|\s|$)'`

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `\S` with `\w` like this:

```
re.search(r'xxx \w+', s)
```

Comment: Hi. My explanation is too simple, but in my case, I have to use \S.

Comment: can you please provide another string example and your expected output

Comment: this expression `xxx [^\r\n\t\f\v ]+` is equivalent to `xxx \S+`, you can do this: `xxx [^\r\n\t\f\v, ]+`  adding the comma

Comment: Oh, that's could be a solution. Thanks.